# Twilio callback signature validation always failing for POST call

Tags: twilio

I have integrated messaging with Twilio and am using Twilio callback to update status of the message in my system. When twilio is responding back with the status, it's always failing for POST api.

I have followed the steps from twilio documentation https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/security#validating-requests

Below is what I am doing :
1. Extract request URL and append query parameters
2. Get parameter map, filter out any request param that is part of this map
3. Validate by calling validate from twilio sdk

I have found that my generated signature is never matching the signature coming from twilio for POST method

Here is my code for getting complete request URL :

```
    StringBuilder requestURL = new 
    StringBuilder(request.getRequestURL().toString());
    String queryString = request.getQueryString();
    String requestURLString = "";

    if (StringUtils.isBlank(queryString))
    {
        requestURLString = requestURL.toString();
    }
    else
    {
        requestURLString = requestURL.append('?').append(queryString).toString();
    }
```

And then I am getting request parameter map like this :

```
       Map<String, String[]> requestParameterMap = request.getParameterMap();
```

Later on I am filtering any extra request parameter that is part of my requestParameterMap :

```
        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(request.getQueryString()))
        {
            Arrays.asList(request.getQueryString().split("&")).stream()
                    .forEach(p -> params.remove(p.split("=")[0]));
        }
```

And then calling twilo util to calculate the signature :

```
       RequestValidator validator = new RequestValidator(authToken);
       isValid = validator.validate(serverURL, params, expectedSignature);
```

Inspecting my request from Twilio console this is how my request is looking like :

**Request** : http://7096a2e1.ngrok.io/api/text/textMessage/updateStatus

**Parameters** :
ApiVersion  2010-04-01
MessageStatus   delivered
SmsSid  SMa72ee979a8374b218107081b04d7eb9a
SmsStatus   delivered
From    +17326418522
To  +19086160992
MessageSid  SMa72ee979a8374b218107081b04d7eb9a
AccountSid  AC134c1c93ef7ef868e85ba9264b4024a1

While debugging in my local server I can see request URL and parameter map are all forming as expected.
Can anyone please help here.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I am not getting any error. The signature I am getting from twilio is different from the one that I am generating from the above mentioned steps. Due to this, I am not able to proceed for further processing on the message received.